# Insert data into a column in my table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I have created a for loop that loops until it hits 10 and outputs INSERT everytime it hits 6 or 8 Now I want to insert a null value in the results column every time it hits a 6 or 8. How might I do this?

```
declare var1 number := 0;
begin
loop exit when var1 > 10; 
if var1 IN (6,8) THEN dbms_output.put_line(' INSERT'); ELSE
dbms_output.put_line(var1);
end if;
var1 := var1 + 1;
end loop;
dbms_output.put_line('Done');
end;
/
```

Table

```
 SQL> describe messages
 Name                                      Null?    Type
  ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

 RESULTS                                            VARCHAR2(60)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SQL> describe messages
 Name                                     Null?    Type
 ---------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 RESULTS                                           VARCHAR2(60)

SQL> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0

SQL> SELECT * FROM messages;

no rows selected

SQL> get a.sql
  1  DECLARE
  2    var1 NUMBER := 0;
  3  BEGIN
  4    LOOP
  5      EXIT WHEN var1 > 10;
  6      IF var1 IN (6,8) THEN
  7        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' INSERT');
  8        INSERT INTO messages VALUES (NULL);
  9      ELSE
 10        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(var1);
 11      END IF;
 12      var1 := var1 + 1;
 13    END LOOP;
 14    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Done.');
 15* END;
 16  
 17  /
0
1
2
3
4
5
INSERT
7
INSERT
9
10
Done.

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         2

SQL> SELECT * FROM messages;

RESULTS
------------------------------------------------------------



SQL>
```

Comment: This relies on autocommit in SQL*Plus. There should really be a `commit` either after the insert or after the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

right after `dbms_output.put_line(' INSERT');`
write your insert statement.

then decide if you want to commit automatically, or manually at the end.